# PHP connect to external Oracle database

Tags: php, linux, networking, oracle11g

I have my PHP installed in Linux server. I needed to connect to an external Oracle database and successfully installed Oracle instant client 12.1.0.2.0.

But now when I run this below simple test connection, I get the following error:

```
ORA-24408: could not generate unique server group name
```

Below is my code:

```
if($c = oci_connect('orcl_username', 'orcl_pswd','//orcl.server.domain.name:1521/servicename')){
    echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.";
    oci_close($c);
} else {
    $err = oci_error();
    $error = $err['message']."\n\n";
    print $error;
}
```

Currently I have this configured in 
`/etc/sysconfig/network` (in my server not oracle server):

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=localhost
```

`/etc/hosts` (in my server not oracle server):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Do I need to have the same configuration in oracle server as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally Ive found a way, my webserver hostname needs to be added in /etc/hosts like this

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 [hostname]

[orcl db ip]   [orcl db hostname]
```

and in /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=[orcl db hostname]
```

cheers!